# When reloading an RTC component that is out of sync, receive error "case-sensitive names while loading on a case insensitive platform"

Tags: rtc, rational-team-concert, ibm-rational

While reloading a project in RTC, I get the following error which prevents the reload from succeeding.

> There were 1 errors.  After correcting the problems, it is recommended that components be reloaded.  The reload will be incremental, loading only the missing items.  You can further reduce the reload time by reloading just the projects out of sync.
>     In order to load /myproject/path/Filename.png an item just loaded must be deleted.  The contents being loaded have case-sensitive names while loading on a case insensitive platform

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Additional info:
RTC Client v3.0.1.5 on Windows 7
RTC Server v4.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the thread "[Suggestions about RTC naming conventions](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/47355/how-insensitive-suggestions-about-rtc-naming-conventions?sort=votes&page=1)", I usually do a:

- delete of the file already loaded in my local worskpace
- refresh said local workspace and accept what the stream proposes for that file
- checking/commit the changes
- reload everything